# Keep all rows according to common numbers in specific columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with 15 columns and I would like to filter the rows that have the same values in common in the columns number: 1,3,5,8,11,14. Basically the columns mass and artificial_mass need to have the same common value. For example from a table like this.

`Input`

```
mass    Ret_time_min    mass    Ret_time_min    mass    Ret_time_min    mass    artifical_mass  Ret_time_min    mass    artifical_mass  Ret_time_min    mass    artifical_mass  Ret_time_min
229 1.516   229 1.503   229 1.516   231 229 1.468   231 229 1.499   231 229 1.63
229 1.573   229 1.597   229 1.585   231 229 1.576   231 229 1.59    233 231 12.89
229 1.905   229 2.004   229 2.186   232 230 11.919  235 233 12.91   235 233 12.929
229 2.303   229 2.139   229 2.242   238 236 0.689   238 236 0.684   238 236 0.689
229 2.59    229 2.291   229 2.365   238 236 0.803   238 236 0.796   238 236 0.788
229 2.737   229 2.484   229 5.41    239 237 0.68    239 237 0.69    239 237 0.691
229 5.398   229 2.589   229 5.593   239 237 6.961   239 237 6.959   239 237 6.966
242 5.163   242 4.612   242 5.141   244 242 12.126  244 242 6.182   244 242 12.503
242 5.194   242 5.123   242 5.475   244 242 12.503  244 242 11.847  245 243 0.065
```

`Output`

```
mass    Ret_time_min    mass    Ret_time_min    mass    Ret_time_min    mass    artifical_mass  Ret_time_min    mass    artifical_mass  Ret_time_min    mass    artifical_mass  Ret_time_min
229 1.516   229 1.503   229 1.516   231 229 1.468   231 229 1.499   231 229 1.63
242 5.163   242 4.612   242 5.141   244 242 12.126  244 242 6.182   244 242 12.503
```

I tried with a simple line: `cat My.File.txt | awk '$1==$3 || $5==$1 && $8==$1 && $10==$1 && $14==$1'` but does not seems to work

Comment: Your code has several issues, first of all you have a [uuoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), then your code will match any rows where `$1==$3`, as you have **OR** condition afterwards. Then you have `$10==$1`, which should be `$11==$1`, other than that, it should work well. I added `NR==1` to print the header.

Comment: Don't add code to the comments, use the [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/489699/edit) button and add it to the question

Comment: @Thor I will put the code on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk 'NR==1 || ( $1==$3 && $1==$5 && $1==$8 && $1==$11 && $1==$14 )' file
```